# plupload AddFile click event doesn't work

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs4, plupload

Problem only in Internet Explorer (8-9 version).
In my ext.js project I use plupload. On my local PC it working fine (in IE and in an other browsers) but on server AddFile button click event doesn't work. I added alert in plupload.full.js file before `p.bind("Silverlight:Init", function () {` and `alert` work but in next row doesn't fall (into bind `Silverlight:Init` function). On my local PC both alert working fine.
Have you any idea?

Comment: First thing you have to check is that your plupload container is visible BEFORE your uploader gets initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to register xap file extension on your IIS.

Comment: Thx. Really *.xap file was not registered on IIS